# Invaders not moving down when they reach far left off screen

Tags: xna

I am having trouble in moving down the invaders when they reach the far left of the screen, however they are having no trouble in moving down when they reach the far right. The code for the movement is shown below:

```
if  (Invaders[0].GetXPos() < 100) // if the first invader element riches the far left of the screen, change direction, and move down four pixels.


{
        AlienDirection = +1;

        for (int Count = 0; Count < 11; Count++)
        {
            Invaders[Count].MoveVertical(4);
        }
    }

    if (Invaders[10].GetXPos() > 924)
    {
        AlienDirection = -1;

        for (int Count = 0; Count < 11; Count++)
        {
            Invaders[Count].MoveVertical(4); // if the first invader element riches the far left of the screen, change direction, and move down four pixels.
        }
    }
```

I don't know whats causing the aliens from not moving down when they gear to the left. Thank you.

Comment: It could be MoveVertical using AlienDirection for something, or the position of Invaders[0] and Invaders[10] not the ones you think. You could solve this quickly by printing to console the position of these two invaders to debug in real time whats going on. Perhaps one condition is always true (?), or you have two errors and one mask the other half the time.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you magic number '924' is wrong.

This could all be refactored to the following

```
if(Invaders[0].GetXPos() < 100 || Invaders[10].GetXPos() > 924) 
{
  AlienDirection = 0 - AlienDirection; // turns -1 into 1 and 1 into -1
  for(int Count = 0; Count < 11; Count++)
  {
    Invaders[Count].MoveVertical(4);
  }
}
```